# Building a new ASP.NET application - Looking for a good framework

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-3, web

I'm starting to build a new large scale ASP.NET web-site which should support large traffic, Ajax. clean pages design (not too heavy, but rather functional), web-services, data-bases, cloud, and other stuff. As being little "outdated" with progress that been made in the ASP.NET arena (was working on other non-web .NET project), i was wondering what are today "best-practices" framework to use when you start building a [very] large new website.

Is MVC 3 is the most accepted one? are they any better, easier to develop, frameworks which are more popular?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use the one you know best and works for you. That's all that really matters. Every framework will require a lot of work to accomplish everything you are trying to accomplish. There is no silver bullet framework that will do away with profiling for performance, or planning server infrastructure, or projecting future traffic patterns.

Answer (score 3):

nancy http://elegantcode.com/2010/11/28/introducing-nancy-a-lightweight-web-framework-inspired-by-sinatra/

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC is by far the most popular and you'll be able to find more resources/get more answers when you get stuck.

Here are some alternate frameworks:

- [FubuMVC](http://fubumvc.com/)
- [OpenRasta](http://openrasta.org/)
- [MonoRail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/)

Comment: For the scope of the question (MVC Frameworks for .NET), yes, I think it is the most popular.

Comment: judging by the tags on StackOverflow, it is at least the most asked about, among all ASP.NET frameworks

Comment: @Zruty: That's not a very effective statistic, because people asking about WebForms tend to just use the ASP.NET tag, whereas people asking about MVC tend to use an MVC tag.

Comment: On SO, perhaps.  I used to answer questions on ASP.Net Forums, and there's about 2.5M threads there, with two major categories being "Web Forms" and "Web Forms Data Controls".  If you Google for ASP.Net Forums, http://forums.asp.net is the first result, not stack overflow.  I don't think the SO population is very representative.  It would be interesting to find some statistic on this, I googled for awhile and didn't really find anything interesting.

Comment: To add to this, on ASP.Net Forums there's 7525 pages of threads on Web Forms, and 4953 pages of threads on Web Forms Data Controls, compared to only 745 pages on MVC.  That's a factor of about 17 to 1!  There's more threads on ASP.Net forums about Web Forms alone than questions with the tag ASP.Net on all of SO!

Comment: True, WebForms is more popular (and much older). From what I understood it sounded like he was looking at MVC frameworks, however it's not completely clear.

Answer (score 1):

For the requirements you've listed, you're probably best starting off with MVC3 on the front-end. For a good, clean design, look into maybe using JQuery UI (MVC3 comes with the core JQuery file, and is designed to integrate well with it. We started a project a couple of years ago using WebForms, but MVC is so vastly superior that we're now migrating everything over to MVC.

Use WCF for web services.

For data access, LINQ to Entities is now mature enough that I think most of the old arguments against it no longer apply. If you want to use a cloud-based database, look into [SQL Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sqlazure/).